# Usage tracking per channel

Tags: google-routes-api

According to this page https://developers.google.com/maps/reporting-and-monitoring/reporting?hl=en#usage-tracking-per-channel
there is opportunity to use param `channel` for tracking usage of api.

How I should to set this param (channel) for tracking usage of api?
Or this functionality not working in Routes API?

When I set param `channel` in request

```
curl -X POST -d '{
    "origin":{
        "location":{
            "latLng":{
                "latitude": 37.419734,
                "longitude": -122.0827784
            }
        }
    },
    "destination":{
        "location":{
            "latLng":{
                "latitude": 37.417670,
                "longitude": -122.079595
            }
        }
    },
    "travelMode": "DRIVE",
    "routingPreference": "TRAFFIC_AWARE",
    "departureTime": "2023-10-15T15:01:23.045123456Z",
    "computeAlternativeRoutes": false,
    "routeModifiers": {
        "avoidTolls": false,
        "avoidHighways": false,
        "avoidFerries": false
    },
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "units": "IMPERIAL"
}' \
\-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Goog-Api-Key: YOUR-API-KEY' \
\-H 'X-Goog-FieldMask: routes.duration,routes.distanceMeters,routes.polyline.encodedPolyline' \
'https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes?key=YOUR-API-KEY&**channel**=3'
```

I get response with message
"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "channel": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'channel' could not be found in request message."

Comment: Documentation has a note now explaining that: Channel data is not available for Maps SDK for Android, Maps SDK for iOS, Places API (New), Address Validation API, Aerial View API, Air Quality API, Map Tiles API, Roads API, Routes API, Pollen API, and Solar API.